# How to display a css animation in the center of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I have an issue perfectly center the animation on small screen-sizes, like <768px. The issue is that the center of the animation needs to be allways in the center of the screen. If the screen gets to small it just floats on the right out of the screen, but i want it to float out equally on every side of the screen.

```
<div class="container" id="" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;" >
    <div class="row vertical-center-row" style="overflow: hidden">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12" 
                style="background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCCCD;
                border-top: 1px solid #CBCCCD; ">
                <div class="spinner">
                     <img class="" src="images/spinner/spinner_bg.png" alt="">
                     <img class="" src="images/spinner/spinner_fg.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 
                            col-sm-8 col-sm-  offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"
                     style="margin-top: 3%;">
                      /*Here is the rest of my content*/
                </div>

            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this structure the content gets centered correctly except the div with class="spinner" for smaller screen-sizes
I tried to accomplish the behaviour i want with media queries in the css file.

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .spinner img{
         max-width:100%;
         height:auto;
         position: absolute;
         top:-309px;
         z-index:-1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .spinner img{
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        position: absolute;
        top:-244px;
         z-index:-1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .spinner img{
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        position: absolute;
        top:-300px;
        z-index:-1;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 766px) {
    .spinner img{
        position: absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }
}
```

The animation gets triggered by adding the css class spin

```
.spin{
    -webkit-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); -moz-transform-origin:           center center } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform- origin: center center } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg);    -webkit-transform-origin: center center transform-origin: center center} }
```

I am very thankfull for any hint or solution to achieve the behaviour i want

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwerasdf/JZ9Rn/) for the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qwerasdf/JZ9Rn/ 
here is fiddle displaying the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can centre the spinner without the need for media-queries by positioning it absolutely with auto margins. The negative top, right, left, bottom positions allow it to remain centred and cropped even when the page is smaller than the spinner. Like so:

```
.spinner img{
    position: fixed;
    top:-100%; right:-100%; left:-100%; bottom:-100%;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JZ9Rn/3/

Comment: The problem is i want the spinner in the background and the content on top of it. I am trying to built an loginpage and if the login button is clicked i want the spinner to be triggered.

Comment: @user3668232 - put the rest of your content above your spinner. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry I forgot an important part in my question the content itself is also centered in the middle I updated the question with a fiddle example. I achieve the centering with display:table and display:table-cell. If I add this class to my content it leads to not wanted behaviour and than still the issue persists that the image is floating out on the right. I want it to be allways in the middle and if the parent gets smaller it just gets cut off at the edges and remains in the middle.
Thank you for your effort so far

Comment: @user3668232 in light of your comments and provision of a jsFiddle I have updated my answer.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for mozilla firefox. Is there a solution for this browser aswell.

Comment: It works for me on Firefox but its slightly off-centre. Try changing the position to fixed: `.spinner img{position: fixed;}`

Comment: Thanks for inadvertandly fixing a problem I've been having!